# Ubuntu 22.10 connected to bluetooth keyboard but not working

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

I have connected my Bluetooth keyboard to my ubuntu 22.10 my laptop is a Lenovo Thinkpad t470, when I type `sudo btmon`  in terminal so I can see the events which sending keyboard, but the system not reacting to these events
The selected is commands that I am getting from the keyboard
[image]

so can anybody help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only, so OS/hardware support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You can ask on [ubuntu.se] instead, and I see you've [already posted there](https://askubuntu.com/q/1453935/301745).

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem until I installed the latest version of bluez (5.66).

Try this:

```bash
wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/bluez-5.66.tar.xz

tar xvf bluez-5.66.tar.xz

cd bluez-5.66

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y libusb-dev libdbus-1-dev libglib2.0-dev libudev-dev libical-dev libreadline-dev python3-docutils

./configure --enable-library

make

sudo make install

reboot
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only, so OS/hardware support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). [ubuntu.se] would be a better spot for this; check out [their tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour). OP has [already posted there](https://askubuntu.com/q/1453935/301745) and it seems to be the same question from a quick glance.